# Display Selected Audio Input/Output device name in menu bar

Tags: macos, audio, menu-bar

Is there a method of displaying which audio input/output device is selected, without needing to click the sound icon in the menu-bar? I'd like to have it displayed permanently in the menu-bar and have it display whatever is actively selected.

Comment: Welcome. Did you try `system_profiler SPAudioDataType` in Terminal and if yes, could you add to your question why it's not sufficient?  Do you want selected audio IO displayed permanently without *any* user action?  If your question can be more specific, the answers will be more relevant.

Comment: If your title means to say you want both, input and output devices displayed in the menu bar directly, I'd have the reservation of space.

Comment: @redarm - I tried https://github.com/deweller/switchaudio-osx before learning about that method. Is there a way to go from text in CLI to menu-bar text?Yeah, possibly that the verbatim name could be too long and in that scenario a nice but not need to have would be the ability to have it display a shortened alias. I'm trying to find a place where I can have the selected input/output displayed always without having to click the volume icon.